# Java Packages and Subpackages printed in alphabetical order

Tags: java, sorting, package

I need to get Packages and Subpackages of Java printed in alphabetical order. I did this:

import java.util.Arrays;

public class J0602 {
    public static void main (String args[]) {

```
    Package[] packs = Package.getPackages();
    String[] packageNames =new String[packs.length];
    int i=0;
    for (Package pack:packs){
        packageNames[i] = pack.getName();
        System.out.println(pack.getName());
        i++;
    }
    Arrays.sort(packageNames);
}
```

}

..but it doesn't work. Is there anything I'm missing about Packages? Why Arrays.sort(); doesn't work here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you know `Arrays.sort()` doesn't work? You are sorting after all of your `System.out.println()` output...

Comment: "it doesn't work" is too vague. Please show the expected output and the actual output. (And address jlordo's comment of the sorting happening *after* the printing...)

Comment: You could try putting your packages in TreeSet and iterating through that TreeSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be because you are Sorting your array after you have printed out the elements.

Try arranging your code this way

```
Arrays.sort(packageNames);
for (Package pack:packs){
         System.out.println(pack.getName());
}
```

Alternatively you could Dump your array in a TreeSet and Iterate through it vis
tr

```
TreeSet<Package> packages = new TreeSet<Package>(Arrays.asList(packageNames));
```

then

```
for (Package pack:packages){
    System.out.println(pack.getName());
}
```

Note that this will remove duplicate packages from your array.